# Autocomplete existing textbox when selection clicked

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a form where there are select option and a textbox. All I want to do is when I select specific option, it will pass the id to query the same table to get another column's value based on ID of selected option and then display the value in a textbox before insert/update the table.

This code will works if both field in my form using select field. So in my opinion, maybe my script for storing value in input text field is totally wrong. Please correct me if I do wrong.

My form code :

```
    <form name="inserform" method="POST">
      <label>Existing Customer Name : </label>
         <select name="existCustName" id="existCustName">
             <option value="">None</option>
                 <?php
                 $custName = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM customers");
                 while ($row = $custName->fetch_assoc())
                 {
                     ?><option id="<?php echo $row['customerID']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['customerID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['customerName']; ?></option><?php
                 }
                 ?>
         </select>br>

      <label>Current Bottle Balance : </label>
         <input type="int" id="currentBal" name="currentBal"></input><br>

      <input name="insert" type="submit" value="INSERT"></input>
    </form>
```

My script code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("change", 'select#existCustName', function(e) {
        var existCustID = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {existCustID: existCustID},
            url: 'existingcustomerlist.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                var $el = $("input#currentBal");
                $el.empty();
                $.each(json, function(k, v) {
                    $el.append("'input[value='" + v.currentBal + "']").val();
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

existingcustomerlist.php code:

```
 <?php 
    include 'config/config.php';
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerID = '" .$_POST['existCustID'] . "'");
    $results = [];
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($results); 
 ?>
```

I need help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to show the results as input text element next to the #currentBal element. Try by changing the script tag inside the success callback as shown below.

```
$.each(json, function (k, v) {
   $el.after("<input type='text' class="currentBalTemp" value='" + v.currentBal + "' />");
});
```

Make sure to remove the .currentBalTemp elements on change event of select otherwise duplication will be shown. Add the below code on change event.

```
$('.currentBalTemp').remove();
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it is the right syntax to store value to input text field because I have done similar to this syntax and yet still no solution. If I'm not mistaken maybe my code is totally wrong starting from line "success:function(json) till the end of line of script"